# Need to bypass the "battery check" when flashing BIOS on GateWay Laptop

Tags: bios, uefi, gateway

Hello all I have a complex issue here and I'm going to try and keep it breif.

The laptop in questions is a Gateway LT41P.

I'm trying to boot from USB to install Linux, but this computer refuses to boot from USB. If you google "gateway lt41p bootable usb" you will see what I mean.

I have determined that it will not boot to USB from UEFI but if I enable the "Leagacy Boot" option through the BIOS I will be able to boot from the USB. My current version of bios doesn't have this option but the newest version does.

Problem is: my laptops battery is dead, getting a new battery is out of the question, and bios utility wont flash with less than 15% battery or the battery removed. I'm hoping there is a way to bypass this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some BIOS installation utilities have a `/forceit` parameter that bypasses all
checks.

Try it, but ensure that you really have the right BIOS version, or the computer
will be completely bricked.

Why is getting a new battery out of the question ?

Comment: I've tried /forceit and it doesn't work. I'm thinking that getting a new battery is really my only choice. It's out of the question because it's $50 and at that price I might as well just buy a raspberry Pi 3. I don't need a battery for this laptop because it isn't going to ever be moved, so I see it as a waste of money.

Comment: [This one](http://www.storebattery.co.uk/gateway-lt41p-11.1v-25wh-laptop-computer-batteries-in-uk-united-kingdom-p-191631.html) is $26.50. [This one](http://www.battery-shop.org/laptop/gateway-lt41p-battery%20packs.htm) is $34.75. Similar for [this one](http://www.battery-store.eu/batteries.php/gateway-lt41p/100147/1003485/169329). And [this one](http://www.batterypack.me/gateway/LT41P_p1080.html). I got these via google and you buy at own risk, shipping not included. In your place I would try my research on black friday.

Comment: Thanks for linking those, that seems like a fair price. I'll wait for Black Friday and see if I can find any good deals.